# Liferay - Differences between deployed and undeployed versions of the same portlet

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I would like to know what are the main differences between a not yet deployed portlet and the same portlet after drop it in Liferay's deploy folder.
Using meld utility I found that the deployed version of the portlet has two new files: **liferay-plugin-package.xml** and **liferay-web.xml**. Also, there are differences in **liferay-display.xml**, **liferay-portlet.xml**, **portlet.xml** and **web.xml**.

What does exactly do the Liferay's deployment process? Is there any documentation reference of that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any documentation, but I haven't searched for that part.
It depends on your application server. For Tomcat liferay it adds its own decriptors, registers the portlets and deploys the application.

After they are registered you can add the portlets to your pages.